# IllegalStateException is not shown as wanted

Tags: java

I am trying out this little calculator program. When I call calculateResult() method, I want to show IllegalStateException error when the secondOperand is zero and the operator is division. But even though, I put an if clause in the calculateResult() to show this error, I don't get the error, but I get infinity. How should I change my code to show this error? Below is my code.

```
public double calculateResult() {

    if (firstOperand != Double.NaN && secondOperand != Double.NaN && operator == '+') {
        return firstOperand + secondOperand;
    }
    else if (firstOperand != Double.NaN && secondOperand != Double.NaN && operator == '-') {
            return firstOperand - secondOperand;
    } 
    else if (firstOperand != Double.NaN && secondOperand != Double.NaN && operator == '*') {
                return firstOperand * secondOperand;
    }
    else if (firstOperand != Double.NaN && secondOperand != Double.NaN && operator == '/') {
            return firstOperand / secondOperand;        

    } 
    else if (firstOperand != Double.NaN && secondOperand != Double.NaN && operator == '%') {
        return firstOperand % secondOperand;        

    }
    else if (secondOperand == '0' || operator == '/'){
        throw new IllegalStateException ("Cannot divided by zero"); //this error never comes up when I print out calcualteResult() method.

    }else {
        return Double.NaN;
    }


}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    // main method
    Calculator first = new Calculator();
    first.setFirstOperand(5.0);
    first.setSecondOperand(0);
    first.setOperator('/');
    first.calculateResult(); // I get [5.0 / 0.0 = Infinity] here...
    System.out.println(first);
```

Comment: To address a different problem, two `NaN` values are not equal. Use `Double.isNan(operand)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't posted the actual code in question, so I can't say for sure, but there are two problems with the zero-detection specifically. First, you're comparing what is either a `Double` or a `double` with a `char` of value `'0'`, not `0`. Remove the single quotes around the numeric value. Additionally, checking for invalid inputs needs to happen *before* you evaluate the operation! If the `operator` is `'/'` (or `'%'`), you need to check for zero before dividing.

This code is a serious mess, and it's simple enough that I'll show how it should be written if you have to use a character for `operator` (something like an enum is nearly always a better choice).

```java
public double calculateResult() {
    // check in one place instead of duplicating
    if(Double.isNaN(first) || Double.isNaN(second)) 
        return Double.NaN;

    // check preconditions *before* calculating
    if(second == 0.0 && (operator == '/' || operator == '%'))
        throw new IllegalStateException("explanation");

    switch(operator) {
        case '+': return first + second;
        case '-': return first - second;
        case '*': return first * second;
        case '/': return first / second;
        case '%': return first % second;
        default: return new IllegalStateException("unsupported operation");
    }
}
```

Comment: Good catches, both. In addition, the test should be `if (secondOperand == '0' && operator == '/')` -- it's a problem if both are true, not just one.

Comment: @keshlam Nope, that clause needs to be eliminated entirely. It's placed *after* the method has already returned from the fourth `if` case. (In fact, this whole method needs to be scrapped and rewritten, but that at least would give semantically correct results.)

Comment: It could be moved before the two cases for division and modulo and would make some sense there.

Answer (score 1):

If `secondOperand` is zero and `operator` is '/', an earlier check will pass, do the computation, and return the properly computed `infinity` value:

```
else if (firstOperand != Double.NaN && secondOperand != Double.NaN && operator == '/') {
        return firstOperand / secondOperand;        

}
```

As has been noted in other answers and comments, some of your code (including this snippet) is wrong in other ways.

You should be using `Double.isNan(operand)` to test whether something is `NaN`, as `NaN` equality rules are a bit strange.  And finally, you don't want to check a double and a character for equality.

But if you want to handle division by zero specially, you need to check for it *before* other conditions that it also meets.

Comment: Thanks.. Now it makes much more sense!

Answer (score 0):

```
else if (secondOperand == 0 && operator == '/'){ ... }
```

You're trying to compare a double value with char ('0')

Comment: Changing to 0 from '0' does not make any change either.

Comment: Because this test should be the first in your method (right now you divide the numbers before you check if one of them is 0)